# overflowing UDP buffer(s)

Tags: udp, overflow, buffer, packet

In Linux, does UDP use the same buffer for incoming and outgoing packets?

If I want to overflow this buffer, it shouldn't matter if I code in C or in Python, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the linux kernel does not define a single or set of buffers for packets per say, but dynamically creates and destroys many buffers as data is passed up and down to/from higher layers (2 and above).

see this very detailed article on linux network, and in particular look at page 4 on how a buffer is connected to a nic for transmit, and then destroyed as soon as transmission is complete: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1312?page=0,0

as for overflowing the buffer, obviously you would need a langague capable of manual memory operations, but linux buffers are a memory location with a control structure associated, so you may not be able to overflow it without the control system interfering.

Comment: Thank you. My goal is to (locally) send UDP messages to a server at such a rate that the server will drop them after some point.   Do you think this is possible in C and in Python? (I'm not asking for the code, of course, just to have a confirmation)

Comment: yes it id definitely possible, because UDP does not implement flow control itself. the network hardware between you and the target however may interfere however.

Comment: Oh, for now it's all on the loopback interface, so it works. Thanks!